# Problems with pods with for architecture arm64 Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods, arm64, podfile

I'm updating a Objective C project the project is 7 years old, I removed useless libraries and now I need to install pods with the actuall libraries but when I build the project shows the following errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_GADAdSizeBanner", referenced from:
      -[AdmobBannerView cargarBannercodAd:viewController:] in AdmobBannerView.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBAdSettings", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FCBBannerView.o
      objc-class-ref in FCBInterView.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBAdView", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FCBBannerView.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBInterstitialAd", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FCBInterView.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GADAppOpenAd", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AdsMediation.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GADBannerView", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AdmobBannerView.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GADExtras", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AdmobBannerView.o
      objc-class-ref in AdmobInterView.o
     (maybe you meant: _OBJC_CLASS_$_GADExtrasBridge)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GADInterstitialAd", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AdmobInterView.o
     (maybe you meant: _OBJC_CLASS_$_GADInterstitialAdBridgeV8)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GADMobileAds", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AdmobBannerView.o
      objc-class-ref in AdsMediation.o
      objc-class-ref in AdmobInterView.o
     (maybe you meant: _OBJC_CLASS_$_GADMobileAdsBridge)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GADRequest", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AdmobBannerView.o
      objc-class-ref in AdsMediation.o
      objc-class-ref in AdmobInterView.o
     (maybe you meant: _OBJC_CLASS_$_GADRequestBridge, _OBJC_CLASS_$_GADRequestBridgeV85 )
  "_kFBAdSizeHeight50Banner", referenced from:
      -[FCBBannerView cargarBannercodFB:viewController:] in FCBBannerView.o
  "_kFBAdSizeHeight90Banner", referenced from:
      -[FCBBannerView cargarBannercodFB:viewController:] in FCBBannerView.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

This is my podfile:

```
project 'coloreaanimalessalvajes.xcodeproj'

# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '13.0'

target 'coloreaanimalessalvajes' do
  # Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
  
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!
  
  pod 'PersonalizedAdConsent'
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'FBAudienceNetwork'
  pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
  pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
  pod 'FBSDKShareKit'
  pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'
  pod 'UnityAds'
  pod 'Bolts'



end
```

I tried to excluded arm64 in the build settings, reintalled pods, change the podfile but didn't work

Comment: Make sure you're getting recent versions from `pod install`. The `Podfile.lock` file shows what was installed.